# How does Agent Vinod link Zeus Group to the terrorist attack?

Tags: plot-explanation, agent-vinod

In ["Agent Vinod"](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1395025) (2012), when and how does Vinod discover that the Zeus Group is behind the plot to explode a bomb in India and blame it on a terrorist organisation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is the real climax of the movie,

After Ruby's dead "Agent Vinod" was seating in front of "Chief Hasan Nawaz", and he is telling that he found a thing (Flash-Drive) in "Colonel"'s body, the man behind this, we can not touch him and we can't do anything while pouring drinks, at that time "Agent Vinod" attached the Flash-Drive to PC and seen who was that person behind this and left before "Chief Hasan Nawaz" turns back,

It was a video recording where "Colonel" and "Metla" talked about "Lashkar" and "Zeus" groups in Flash-Drive.